# why this java code can not use escape analysis?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot, escape-analysis

my code is here =>

```
class PointHolder {
    private Point point;

    public PointHolder(Point point) {
        this.point = point;
    }
    //getter
}
class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    //getter setter
}

public class Escape {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
            test4(i);
        }
    }
    static int foo;
    public static void test4(int x) {
        PointHolder pointHolder = new PointHolder(new Point(x + 2, 42));
        foo = pointHolder.getPoint().getX();
    }
}
```

use the jitwatch, i could see the pointHolder is not been allocated, but `new Point(x+2, 42)` is still been allocated.

[image: ea]

[image: es2]

i could not figure out why

Comment: can you show us the output. I am not fully understanding your issue here

Comment: The posted code would not compile. `foo` is assigned a value but never declared, and a `getX()` method on the `Point` class is referenced but never defined. Please post your most current, up-to-date code if you expect us to help you.

Comment: @roottraveller hi，i upload the pic. The var pointHolder's allocation has been eliminated, but allocation of `new Point(x + 2,42)` not been  eliminated.

Comment: What do you mean "not been eliminated" - you mean not deallocated?

Comment: @mario_sunny according to the `escape analysis`, the scope of `new Point()` is in the test4 method, so the allocation of `new Point()` should be eliminated.

Comment: Escape analysis is done as part of the JIT compilation, not java bytecode compilation.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn yes，the pic is the jitwatch result after jit compilation.

Comment: That is still the bytecode. Look at the actual assembly.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn you want see the assembly code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape Analysis in HotSpot C2 compiler is rather simple. It never attempted to detect *all* possible objects that do not escape the compilation scope. In particular, it does not currently handle a multi-level reference tree.

In your example, a reference to a newly allocated `Point` is assigned to an object field: `PointHolder.point`. JIT treats this assignment as an escape of `Point` object and thus does not eliminate the allocation.

One particular exception is boxing-unboxing: HotSpot handles boxing-unboxing methods specially. E.g. it would be still able to eliminate allocation of `Integer` object when it is assigned to an `IntegerHolder` field.

This problem is not something unsolvable though - it's rather a missed optimization opportunity. Graal JIT is better in this sence - in the given example it *does* eliminate both `Point` and `PointHolder` allocations.